# Java Exit Code 13?

Tags: java

How can I fix this error to startup eclipse ? 
Eclipse.ini file I have installed jdk 7u55

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316      
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

No matter how I edit the eclipse.ini eclipse won't run and gives me exit code 13 .

Comment: How can I fix this ?

Comment: I saw a lot of duplicates but none of them helped me @CoderNeji

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\javaw.exe....

-vmargs....

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6....

I think its an error of not setting the eviroment values

Answer (score 0):

I have the --launcher.appendVmargs after the -vm and is working for me:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/javaw.exe
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
```

Comment: Have you tried to decrease the -Xmx memory to 512m? And with a 64bits JDK?

Comment: just tried that didnt work either

Comment: To be straight save your workspace data... Uninstall eclipse and java... and then reinstall both of them.... Problem solved... you have all your required data too.... the time you consumed in this... By this time you would have done this...